# Calculate and show the difference between the max value and min value from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
vacc = pd.read_csv("Vacc.csv", parse_dates=['date'],dayfirst=True) 

CountryInterest = vacc.query("country == 'United Kingdom' | country == 'Romania' | country == 'Bulgaria' | country == 'Brazil' | country == 'United Arab Emirates'")
Interest = CountryInterest['country']

vaccinated = vacc.query("date >= '20/01/2021' & date <= '03/02/2021'")
VaccCountry = vaccinated['people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred']
```

[image: the image is to show you the names of the columns]

Comment: `VaccCountry.max()-VaccCountry.min()`?

Comment: Thank you !! I just don't know how to combine VaccCountry with Interest .. this is the problem I need to sort : From 5th to 15th March 2021, what proportion of the population of each of the following countries was fully vaccinated:                                            
• United Kingdom;
• Romania;
• Bulgaria;
• Brazil;
• United Arab Emirates?

Comment: And I need just calculate the difference between max and min from people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred column for each of the five countries for the given dates.

Comment: Provide a sample of your data (not with screenshots). For example, you could use the output of `vacc.head().to_dict()` in your OP. Also include your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`numpy.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html):

```
np.ptp(vaccinated['people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred'])
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't see the values, and I can't comment yet.

```
vacc['people_fully_vaccinated_per_hundred'].describe()
```

The above should give you the min,max, count, and mean etc